# state management for complex json using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

question on architecting React App and state management with huge tree structured list with react hooks -
i am getting a huge list of JSON and when ever there is an update or notification through socket i will be receiving the same tree structured JSON with the small leaf node being changed and it is re-rendering the whole child components, I know with redux i can structure the app with passing only specific state objects and ignoring the other and saving them in store  how should i structure my component  with react-hooks like managing this huge JSON object

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way of doing it:

Save your big JSON in a state and set multiple `useEffect()` to run based on changes on specific properties of that big JSON tree. Update the components related to those properties inside each respective `useEffect()`.

```js
function App() {

  // THIS IS TO AVOID THE EFFECTS TO RUN ON 1ST RENDER (WHEN STATE IS 1ST CREATED)
  const isFirstRender = React.useRef(true);

  // THIS IS YOUR BIG JSON TREE
  const [deepState, setDeepState] = React.useState({
    propA: {
      propAA: false
    },
    propB: {
      propBB: false
    }
  });
  
  // THIS SIMULATES YOUR 1ST SOCKET MSG
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    setTimeout(
      ()=>setDeepState((prevState) => ({
        propA: {
          propAA: false
        },
        propB: {
          propBB: true
        }
      })),1500);
  },[]);

  // THIS SIMULATES A 2ND SOCKET MSG
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    setTimeout(
      ()=>setDeepState((prevState) => ({
        propA: {
          propAA: true
        },
        propB: {
          propBB: true
        }
      })),3000);
  },[]);
  
  // THIS WILL UPDATE COMPONENTS THAT CARE ABOUT ONE SPECIFIC DEEP PROPERTY
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    if (isFirstRender.current === true) {
      return;
    }
    console.log('Deep property propB.propBB has changed to: ' + deepState.propB.propBB);
    console.log('Will updateComponents that depend on propB.propBB');
  },[deepState.propB.propBB]);

  // THIS WILL UPDATE COMPONENTS THAT CARE ABOUT ANOTHER SPECIFIC DEEP PROPERTY      
  React.useEffect(()=>{
  if (isFirstRender.current === true) {
    return;
  }
    console.log('Deep property propA.propAA has changed to: ' + deepState.propA.propAA);
    console.log('Will updateComponents that depend on propA.propAA');
  },[deepState.propA.propAA]);
  
  // THIS IS TO AVOID THE EFFECTS TO RUN ON 1ST RENDER (WHEN STATE IS 1ST CREATED)
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    isFirstRender.current = false;
  },[]);
  
  return(
    <div>Some Component</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```